# In WIX Bookings, how to read the the member's currently selected service

Tags: service, member, velo

In the WIX site I am working on there are a couple of pages created by Wix Bookings:

The member can select a service on the Book Online page, and then navigate to other pages and finalily confirm the booking.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkZlg.png)

I need to know (using Velo code) the service selected by the member on the Calendar page next to Book Online, after the member selected a service. I.e. the "Service Name" displayed on the Calendar page.

All the pages were created by Wix Bookings, so all those elements are unaccessible via Velo code.

Could anyone please advise how to read the member's selected service via Velo code? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkgnE.png)